# Is there any way to start with a POST request using Selenide

Tags: selenide

I'm trying to start a Selenide test with a POST request to my application.

Instead of a simple `open(/startpoint)`

I would like to do something like `open(/startpoint, stuff=foo,stuff2=bar)`

Is there any way to do that?

I'm asking this because the original page which posts to this start point depends on external providers that are often offline (development environment) and so will often fail too early (and are not the subject of the test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Selenium doesn't have the ability to do a POST request, unless you loaded a dummy HTML page with a `<form>` tag on it (as a unit test) and a submit button (such as src/test/resources/FormPage.html).   So, the alternative is to build a HTTP post query from scratch using Apache HttpUtils library.  I usually use the latter method (as an integration test), although the former would work I think.